# What does "se receta la muy pilla" mean?

Tags: significado

I am reading a story from a Mexican book called *La cucaracha comelona*.

I encountered the phrase "se receta la muy pilla" but I can't nail down what this means.

**Context:**

> La cucaracha tanto comió, que una indigestión le dio. Pero un té de
> manzanilla ***se receta la muy pilla***.

Researching, the verb "recetar" means to prescribe. I did not find a reflexive form recetarse. So I think maybe it's the passive voice "he was prescribed the tea"(but we don't know who prescribed it to him). Am I correct in this assumption?

"Pillar" means to catch or get. Firstly I fail to see the meaning this word adds to the phrase. Secondly "pillar" is not an adjective or adverb so the use of ***muy*** confuses me here as well.

Also what does "comelona" mean? I can not find a translation anywhere.

Comment: **pillo/pilla** means **astuto/astuta** [bold, clever, crafty] in Chile, and I can see in Mexico too, so probably in many other Latinamerican countries also does it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not a passive *se* as such, but rather a reflexive *se*. Most transitive verbs can be made reflexive in this manner, so there is no need to list a specific pronomial form in the dictionary. So "it prescribes itself a chamomile tea."

In this case, "pilla" looks like a nominalized adjective.  Just as "el malo" = "the bad man" (i.e. "the villain"; "el malo del cuento"), "la pilla" is "the rascal" since "pilla/o" means "rascally." "La muy pilla" intensifies it ("the great rascal"), but in context I would say it might convey almost a humorous tone, like "the little rascal." So, putting it together:

> But the little rascal prescribes itself a chamomile tea.

Further, "comelona" means someone who eats a great deal. The male form is "comelón", and in some countries people say "comilón" and "comilona" instead.

Comment: @Leo why "her"? A cockroach is normally referred to as "it". Unless there is some context in that book that I do not know...

Comment: la muy pilla refers back to la cucaracha, which is feminine.

Comment: @WalterMitty - Claro que sí, pero en inglés se les refiere a los animales como "it", si su género no se especifica de antemano. Pues el término la cucaracha se refiere tanto a las hembras como a los machos, no se sabe el sexo del bicho.

Comment: Claro.  Hablamosde género liguistico.